# How to express the type of a constrained-generic function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I can define a function

```
func myGenericFunc<A: SomeProtocol>(_ a: A) -> A { ... }
```

Now I want to type a variable to hold exactly this kind of function, but I find I can't spell the type:

```
let f: (SomeProtocol) -> SomeProtocol // doesn't express the genericity
let f: <A: SomeProtocol>(A) -> A // non-existent syntax
```

Is there any way I can express this directly?

Note that in particular I want `f` to *still be generic*: it should accept any `SomeProtocol` conformer (so no fixing the generic type parameter in advance). In other words: anything I can do with `myGenericFunc` I want to also be able to do with `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is **no**, you can't use a single variable to hold different function implementations. A variable needs to hold something concrete for the compiler to allocate the proper memory layout, and it can't do it with a generic construct.

If you need to hold different closure references, you can use a generic type alias:

```
typealias MyGenericFunction<T: SomeProtocol> = (T) -> T

var f1: MyGenericFunction<SomeConformerType> // expanded to (SomeConformerType) -> SomeConformerType
var f2: MyGenericFunction<AnotherConformerType> // expanded to (AnotherConformerType) -> AnotherConformerType
```

Comment: That's equivalent to `var f: (SomeConformerType) -> SomeConformerType`. But it doesn't let me pass *different* `SomeProtocol`-conforming types to `f`. I'll update the question to highlight this explicitly.

Comment: @Tikitu you can pass any type that conforms to the protocol

Comment: @Tikitu I updated my answer with an example of how you can do that

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't expect I can pass a `SomeConformerType` to `f2` in your answer. Right?

Comment: Just saw your edit in the question, nope, you can't do that in Swift. Will update my answer with this

Comment: @Tikitu updated the answer, let me know if this addresses your query.

Comment: I think the bit about the generic type alias is a red herring; if you remove that I'll happily accept the rest.

Comment: @Tikitu I won't retract useful information from the answer, and I'll be grateful if you also won't. I reordered a little bit the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

My original question was about expressing the type directly, but it's also interesting to notice that this is impossible for a different reason:

```
func myGenericFunc<A: SomeProtocol>(_ a: A) -> A { ... }
let f = myGenericFunc // error: generic parameter 'A' could not be inferred
```

You could see this as the "deeper reason" there's no spelling for the generic type I wanted: a variable (as opposed to a function) simply cannot be generic in that sense.